# iOS 10 Table View Controller ignoring preferred content size

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios10, xcode8.2

I have a Table View that I am using as a popover on an iPad app.  It is formatted to be tall and thin.  It looks correct in the IB storyboard.  I have set preferred sizes everywhere I can find and I've even tried to set it programmatically in the method that presents the popover.  But no matter what I do, it always shows the popover as a full screen.  I have other popovers in the app that display an image in a UIView and they all follow the preferred size perfectly.  This is driving me nuts.

[image]

Comment: I think you cannot add a tableviewcontroller into popovercontroller. what you need to do is create tableview only programmatically and then add that view to popover. that is easier and simpler. also, pls show code what you tried.